# XNA Displaying/Drawing from a text file

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, maps, text

I wrote this code in the Load Content of XNA 4.0 for reading the star map, after actually adding it to my content, and I have no idea how to write/draw it onto my application, any suggestions?

```
    string starmap = null;

        using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("starmap.txt"))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                starmap = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Why would rendering content that you loaded from text be different than rendering content from a hardcoded variable, or from a procedural generator, or from a webservice, or any other data source? What particular problem are you experiencing with this text content that you need help overcoming?